# Loop through fetched object in native react

Tags: reactjs, native

I'm trying to build an application that fetches JSON from remote URL, then using this JSON to build few views.

Here's my app code:

```
/**
 * DeepThoughts Template
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
} = React;

var REQUEST_URL = 'http://www.geektime.co.il/appApi/main.json';

var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      thought: '',
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
      this.fetchData();
  },
  fetchData: function() {
      fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
          this.setState({
              thought: { title: responseData[0].title, content:responseData[0].content },
          });
      })
      .done();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>
            {this.state.thought.title}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            {this.state.thought.content}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var windowSize = Dimensions.get('window');

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    bottom: 0,
    flex: .1,
    width: windowSize.width,
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#666666',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

This works, however I haven't found any documentation on how to create a for or while loop, or even map the array of objects in order to create views according to the number of items in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a for loop, but will essentially call the funtion on every element in tables (in this case tables is the array of tables I'm iterating through), and then return the jsx div and add that to list, so when I place {list} inside the return of the render function, it will display all the elements, almost like ng-repeat in angularjs. I hope this helps.

```
render: function() {
    console.log(this.props);
    var i = 0;
  var list = this.props.tables.map(function(tableDataProps){
      if(i==4){
      i=1;
    return <div>  
        <div className='row' style={styles.border}></div>
        <div className="col-sm-3 col-sm-12" style={styles.padding}>
                <h1 style={styles.headings}>{tableDataProps.title}</h1>
                <h2>{tableDataProps.id}</h2>
                <CurrentTable jobs={tableDataProps} /> 
            </div>
            </div>    
      }
      else{
      i++;
    return  <div className="col-sm-3 col-sm-12" style={styles.padding}>
                <h1 style={styles.headings}>{tableDataProps.title}</h1>
                <CurrentTable jobs={tableDataProps} /> 
            </div>
      }
  });
  return <div>
    {list}
  </div>
}
```